# Issue while downloading RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, ubuntu, package, cran

Warning: invalid package ‘RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning message:

```
In install.packages("RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz", lib = "/home/anirudh/Downloads/",  :
  installation of package ‘RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

`install.packages('RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz',lib='/home/anirudh/Downloads',repos=NULL`)

```
Warning: invalid package ‘RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning message:
In install.packages("RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz", lib = "/home/anirudh/Downloads",  :
  installation of package ‘RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What version of R are you running?  32 bit or 64 bit?  Windows or Linux?

Comment: The way you've specified this, you're trying to stall a locally saved package. Do you want to install it from CRAN (i.e., `install.packages("RPostgreSQL")`)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
install.packages("/home/anirudh/Downloads/RPostgreSQL_0.4.tar.gz",
                 repos = NULL, type="source")
```